# Minium is throwing error with glue and browser

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Does anyone knows why Minium (Selenium Webdriver Java + Cucumber) is throwing this error trace?

I have been looking for hours and nothing seems to fix this error.

**Proyect structure**

[image]

**Java:**

```
import minium.cucumber.MiniumCucumber;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.cli.Main;
import ModulosComunesWeb.*;

@RunWith(MiniumCucumber.class)
/*@CucumberOptions(
        features = "LO-PPE-WEB-AltaFavoritos.feature"
    //  ,glue={"stepDefinition"}
        )
@CucumberOptions(

        features= "LO-PPE-WEB-AltaFavoritos.feature"
)*/
public class LOFavoritasIT {


}
```

> 2018-07-10 12:35:08.977  WARN 17180 --- [engine-thread-0] minium.cucumber.internal.MiniumBackend   : Could not load glue src/test/resources/steps
>
> org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'browser' defined in minium.web.config.WebElementsConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'browser' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wd' defined in minium.web.config.WebElementsConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'wd' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html (minium/minium.js#23)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1893)
>           at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)

Comment: Without knowing your code I would guess it's related to this part of the message `The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property`.

Comment: i added the code

Comment: What did you related to the cited error message and the provided link in the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your Google Chrome browser version to download the [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) that match the browser version. If you are not using the latest version, download the chromedriver that match your browser version and copy the ".exe" file to the **drivers** folder of Minium Developer.

If you have the latest Google Chrome browser version, Minium Developer can download the latest webdrivers for you: https://minium.vilt.io/docs/developer/minium-developer/#update-webdrivers

Comment: Better using Minium IDE instead of Spring framework, thanks